# Horror movie where mirrors are a gateway to Hell

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

My recollection of this movie is very poor, it's been easily 10 years since I seen it...

It's an American movie from the 1980s.

I think the story line revolves around a bunch of paranormal researchers / scientists that are investigating a relic found in a church. The movie takes place in that church.

Loads of freaky stuff happens, I vaguely remember water pooling on the ceiling.

Satan is definitely involved at some stage.

The female lead is sucked through a mirror, she never makes it out. I think it's established at some point that mirrors are a gateway to Hell.

At the very end, when the good guys have won, one of them reaches out to touch a mirror, I think he can hear the female lead calling for help. And that's were the movie ends.

As far as I can remember, there are no notable actors in it.

If someone can help me out, I *guarantee* * I'll send you some gold in the post.

> * Not a guarantee

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is probably **Prince of Darkness** from John Carpenter.
IMDB article: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093777/

Alice Cooper had a short appearance in the film.

Comment: Ha! That's it alright! Cheers Sunzi. Your gold is in the post!